# PHP Email Script | Email not showing up in inbox

Tags: php

I have a very simple contact form like the one below that submits to a php script that is supposed to send an email to the one specified. But nothing is appearing in my inbox. I thought maybe it is just delayed but it has been about 3 hours now with nothing showing up!

**Contact Form**

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactForm" method="post" action="assets/send_form_email.php">
              <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                <label for="question">Question/Comment</label>
                <textarea name="question" id="question" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin: 0px 0px 10px; width: 303px; height: 54px;"></textarea>
              </fieldset>
          </form>
```

**PHP Script **

```
   <? php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "";
    $email_subject = "New Contact Form | Website";
    echo $_POST['email'];
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo $_POST['question'];

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['question'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
        $error_message. = 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
        $error_message. = 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($question) < 5) {
        $error_message. = 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }
    $email_message. = "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Question/Comment: ".clean_string($question)."\n";
    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); ?>
    <!--
    include your own success html here -->
    Thank you
    for contacting us.We will be in touch with you very soon. <? php
 } ?>
```

I really can not figure out what is wrong with the code to fix it. Someone please help.

Comment: Did you check "Spam" folder?

Comment: where is your mail() function ?

Comment: Is your server setup to send emails? If you are using XAMPP be sure you have set this feature up!

Comment: if it appears in spam, i guess SMTP of your webhost is blacklisted or you need more details in your header informations

Comment: @FaceOfJock same line as $headers var has

Comment: If you are sending this from localhost - it probably has been stored somewhere on disk. Try to test it on real web server configured correctly.

Comment: I am sending it on a real live server.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my question until 8 hours after posting so I read into my host details and the email must be hosted with them that the message is going to. So I set up a new email address and then forwarded it to the email address I normally use. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure that `mail()` function works and there is no fail.
Something like this:

```
if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
    echo 'Sent';
}
```

Comment: Okay, I put your code into mine and added an `else` statement that said to `echo 'There is something wrong!';` And I received the else side. Can I add something to echo the error?

Comment: Check if sendmail is running on the server.

Comment: Check /var/log/maillog or something